# I would like to know how to check if a file input is empty and return a boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var upload = function() {
    var file = false;
    $("input[name=nota_fiscal]").on("change", function() {
        if ($(this).get(0).files.length === 0) {
            file = false;
            console.log("No files selected.");
        } else {
            console.log("Files selected.");
            file = true;
        }
    });
    return file;
}

console.log(upload());
```

```html
<script src="https://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://metroui.org.ua/js/metro.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://metroui.org.ua/css/metro.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-icons.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-responsive.css" />

<div class="grid">
    <div class="row cells12">
        <div class="cell auto-size">
            <label for="nome">Importar lojas apartir de arquivo </label>
            <div class="input-control file full-size" data-role="input">
                <input type="file" name="arquivo_csv" size="20" />
                <button class="button"><span class="mif-upload"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" name="uploadcsv" class="" disabled value="Upload" />
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$("input[name=arquivo_csv]")`?

Comment: you don't need to listen on change event for the input

Comment: actually I would like to know with returns the value of variable file within the change function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var upload = function () {
            var file;
            if ( $("input[name=arquivo_csv]").get(0).files.length === 0) {
                file = false;
                console.log("No files selected.");
            } else {
                console.log("Files selected.");
                file = true;
            }
            return file;
    }
 

    $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
       console.log(upload()); 
    });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://metroui.org.ua/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://metroui.org.ua/js/metro.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://metroui.org.ua/css/metro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://metroui.org.ua/css/metro-responsive.css">


<div class="grid">
                                <div class="row cells12">
                                    <div class="cell auto-size">
                                        <label for="nome">Importar lojas apartir de arquivo </label>
                                        <div class="input-control file full-size" data-role="input">
                                            <input type="file" name="arquivo_csv" size="20" />
                                            <button class="button"><span class="mif-upload"></span></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" name="uploadcsv" class=""  value="Upload" />
                            </div>
```